# Looping through an array of images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to loop through an array of images and display each image one by one on the click of a single button.

Here is my code.

This is in the viewDidLoad method:

```
    arrayImg = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"samsung_logo_small.jpg"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Small_logo_splash.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red_logos_small.png"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"li-logo-small-drshdw.gif"],
            nil];
```

Here is my button in which I am looping through the images

```
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {
for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrayImg count]; i++) {
    [img setImage:[arrayImg objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

}

The problem is that it is only showing the last image, not all of the images.

What I am doing wrong here?

I found 2 questions like this on but could not find the answer.

Comment: The problem is that you're looping through all the images at once, not one per click.

Comment: What did you expect from looping thru images and setting all of them one after another to the same image view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following to `YourClass.m` file:

```
@interface YourClass() {
    int variableName;
}
```

@end

in `viewDidLoad` initialize variableName to `0`.

```
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender 
{
    if (variableName == arrayImg.count)
    {
        variableName = 0;
    }
    [img setImage:[arrayImg objectAtIndex:classVariable]];
    variableName++
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.....but please answer a few questions. When I wrap the IF Statement in brackets it does not work, but after that it does work, what is the reason? Also why is the arrayImg.count being set equal to the variable name?

Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh You must be using brackets for the `if statement` incorrectly, then. `arrayImg.count` is not being *set* to the variable name, it's being *checked against* `variableName`. Look into the differences between `=` and `==`, you must know this.

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh I hope you have got my answer right as explained by rebello95. Thank You.

Comment: I am adding the brackets of the statement like this

    if (imgCount == arrayImg.count){
        imgCount = 0;
        [img setImage:[arrayImg objectAtIndex:imgCount]];
        imgCount++;
    }

With brackets images are not being displayed on btn click but without brackets it is wiring just fine, I am not getting any error or warnings

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh See edited answer. And also, not that, adding bracket to that `if` wasn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show one image at a time then why loop? You can do it like this:

```
 static int index;

- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

  [img setImage:[arrayImg objectAtIndex:index]];
   index = index == arrayImg.count - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
}
```

Comment: Your's is the better answer (usage of static). You could have used if-else for better readability though.

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad`, add one more line:

```
[buttonName setTag:0];
```

Here change in btn event:

```
- (IBAction)btn:(UIButton *)sender {

   [img setImage: [arrayImg objectAtIndex: [sender tag]]];

   [sender setTag: [sender tag]+1];

   if ([sender tag] > [arrayImg count]) {
     [sender setTag: 0];
   }
}
```

This will help you in memory management as well, because here no other extra flag variable required to hold your integer value, whereas your `UIButton` object only will hold.

Hope this will help you to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Suggestion. You can have `- (IBAction)btn:(UIButton *)sender {` instead of `- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {` and then directly access `sender.tag`.

Comment: @RichaSharma : Yup that is also possible. Updated ans respectively.

Comment: The first line is unnecessary because `UIView` defaults to a `tag` of `0`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you're looping through all of the images on a single click.

A better approach might be to display an image after a click but instead of looping just increment a variable that represents your index value by 1. This way after each click the next image is displayed.

The other approach would be to use a timer.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(displayNextImage:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```